# Serious Memory Leak When Iteratively Parsing XML Files

Tags: r, xml, memory-leaks

### Context

When iterating over a set of Rdata files (each containing a character vector of HTML code) that are loaded, analyzed (via [**XML**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) functionality) and then removed from memory again, I experience a **significant** increase in an 
R process' memory consumption (killing the process eventually).

It just seems like

- freeing objects via `free()`,
- removing them via `rm()` and
- running `gc()`

do not have any effects, so the memory consumption cumulates until there's no more memory left.

### EDIT 2012-02-13 23:30:00

Thanks to valuable insight shared by the author and maintainer of package [**XML**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html), Duncan Temple Lang (again: I really appreciate it very much!), the problem seems to be closely related to the way external pointers are freed and how garbage collection is handled in the XML package. Duncan issued a bug-fixed version of the package (3.92-0) that consolidated certain aspects of parsing XML and HTML and features an improved garbage collection where it's not necessary anymore to explicitly free the object containing the external pointer via `free()`. You find the source code and a Windows binary at Duncan's [Omegahat website](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/).

---

### EDIT 2012-02-13 23:34:00

Unfortunately, the new package version still does not seem to fix the issues I'm encountering in the little little example that I've put together. I followed some suggestion and simplified the example a bit, making it easier to grasp and to find the relevant functions where things seem to go wrong (check functions `./lib/exampleRun.R` and `.lib/scrape.R`).

---

### EDIT 2012-02-14 15:00:00

Duncan suggested trying to force to free the parsed document explicitly via `.Call("RS_XML_forceFreeDoc", html)`. I've included a logical switch in the example (`do.forcefree` in script `./scripts/memory.R`) that, if set to `TRUE`, will do just that. Unfortunately, this made my R console crash. It'd be great if someone could verify this on their machine! Actually, the doc **should** be freed automatically when using the latest version of XML (see above). The fact that it isn't seems to be a bug (according to Duncan).

---

### EDIT 2012-02-14 23:12:00

Duncan pushed yet another version of XML (3.92-1) to his Omegahat website [Omegahat website](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/). This should fix the issue in general. However, I seem to be out of luck with my example as I still experience the same memory leakage.

---

### EDIT 2012-02-17 20:39:00 > SOLUTION!

YES! Duncan found and fixed the bug! It was a little typo in a Windows-only script which explained why the bug didn't show in Linux, Mac OS etc. Check out the latest version [3.92-2.](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/)! Memory consumption is now as constant as can be when iteratively parsing and processing XML files!

Special thanks again to Duncan Temple Lang and thanks to everyone else that responded to this question!

---

### >>> LEGACY PARTS OF THE ORIGINAL QUESTION <<<

### Example Instructions (edited 2012-02-14 15:00:00)

1. Download folder **'memory'** from my [**Github repo**](https://github.com/Rappster/RappsterMisc/tree/master).
2. Open up the script `./scripts/memory.R` and set a) your *working directory* at **line 6**, b) the *example scope* at **line 16** as well c) whether to force the freeing of the parsed doc or not at **line 22**. Note that you can still find the old scripts; they are "tagged" by an "**LEGACY**" at the end of the filename.
3. Run the script.
4. Investigate the latest file `./memory_<TIMESTAMP>.txt` to see the increase in logged memory states over time. I've included two text files that resulted from my own test runs.

### Things I've done with respect to memory control

- making sure a loaded object is removed again via `rm()` at the end of each iteration.
- When parsing XML files, I've set argument `addFinalizer=TRUE`, removed all R objects that have a reference to the parsed XML doc before freeing the C pointer via `free()` and  removing the object containing the external pointer.
- adding a `gc()` here and there.
- trying to follow the advice in Duncan Temple Lang's [**notes**](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/MemoryManagement.html#Problems) on memory management when using its XML package (I have to admit though that I did not fully comprehend what's stated there)

*EDIT 2012-02-13 23:42:00:*
As I pointed out above, explicit calls to `free()` followed by `rm()` should not be necessary anymore, so I commented these calls out.

### System Info

- Windows XP 32 Bit, 4 GB RAM
- Windows 7 32 Bit, 2 GB RAM
- Windows 7 64 Bit, 4 GB RAM
- R 2.14.1
- XML 3.9-4
- XML 3.92-0 as found at http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/

### Initial Findings as of 2012-02-09 01:00:00

1. Running the webscraping scenario on several machines (see section "System Info" above) always busts the memory consumption of my R process after about 180 - 350 iterations (depending on OS and RAM).
2. Running the plain rdata scenario yields constant memory consumption ***if and only if*** you set an explicit call to the garbage collector via `gc()` in each iteration; else you experience the same behavior as in the webscraping scenario.

### Questions

1. Any idea what's causing the memory increase?
2. Any ideas how to work around this?

### Findings as of 2012-02-013 23:44:00

Running the example in `./scripts/memory.R` on several machines (see section "System Info" above) still busts the memory consumption of my R process after about 180 - 350 iterations (depending on OS and RAM).

There's still an evident increase in memory consumption and even though it may not appear to be that much when just looking at the numbers, my R processes always died at some point due to this.

Below, I've posted a couple of time series that resulted from running my example on a WinXP 32 Bit box with 2 GB RAM:

### TS_1 (XML 3.9-4, 2012-02-09)

29.07
33.32
30.55
35.32
30.76
30.94
31.13
31.33
35.44
32.34
33.21
32.18
35.46
35.73
35.76
35.68
35.84
35.6
33.49
33.58
33.71
33.82
33.91
34.04
34.15
34.23
37.85
34.68
34.88
35.05
35.2
35.4
35.52
35.66
35.81
35.91
38.08
36.2

### TS_2 (XML 3.9-4, 2012-02-09)

28.54
30.13
32.95
30.33
30.43
30.54
35.81
30.99
32.78
31.37
31.56
35.22
31.99
32.22
32.55
32.66
32.84
35.32
33.59
33.32
33.47
33.58
33.69
33.76
33.87
35.5
35.52
34.24
37.67
34.75
34.92
35.1
37.97
35.43
35.57
35.7
38.12
35.98

### Error Message associated to TS_2

```
[...]
Scraping html page 30 of ~/data/rdata/132.rdata
Scraping html page 31 of ~/data/rdata/132.rdata
error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
error : Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
I/O error : write error
Scraping html page 32 of ~/data/rdata/132.rdata
Fehler in htmlTreeParse(file = obj[x.html], useInternalNodes = TRUE, addFinalizer =     TRUE): 
 error in creating parser for (null)
> Synch18832464393836
```

### TS_3 (XML 3.92-0, 2012-02-13)

20.1
24.14
24.47
22.03
25.21
25.54
23.15
23.5
26.71
24.6
27.39
24.93
28.06
25.64
28.74
26.36
29.3
27.07
30.01
27.77
28.13
31.13
28.84
31.79
29.54
32.4
30.25
33.07
30.96
33.76
31.66
34.4
32.37
35.1
33.07
35.77
38.23
34.16
34.51
34.87
35.22
35.58
35.93
40.54
40.9
41.33
41.6

### Error Message associated to TS_3

```
[...]
---------- status: 31.33 % ----------

Scraping html page 1 of 50
Scraping html page 2 of 50
[...]
Scraping html page 36 of 50
Scraping html page 37 of 50
Fehler: 1: Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
2: Memory allocation failed : growing buffer
```

---

### Edit 2012-02-17: please help me verifying counter value

You'd do me a huge favor if you could run the following code. 
**It won't take more than 2 minutes of your time**. 
All you need to do is

1. Download an [Rdata file](https://raw.github.com/Rappster/RappsterMisc/master/memory/data/seed/seed.rdata) and save it as `seed.Rdata`.
2. Download the script containing my [scraping function](https://raw.github.com/Rappster/RappsterMisc/master/memory/lib/scrape.R) and save it as `scrape.R`.
3. Source the following code after setting the working directory accordingly.

Code:

```
setwd("set/path/to/your/wd")
install.packages("XML", repos="http://www.omegahat.org/R")
library(XML)
source("scrape.R")
load("seed.rdata")
html <- htmlParse(obj[1], asText = TRUE)
counter.1 <- .Call("R_getXMLRefCount", html)
print(counter.1)
z <- scrape(html)
gc()
gc()
counter.2 <- .Call("R_getXMLRefCount", html)
print(counter.2)
rm(html)
gc()
gc()
```

I'm particularly interested in the values of `counter.1` and `counter.2` which **should** be `1` in both calls. In fact, it is on all machines that Duncan has tested this on. However, as it turns out `counter.2` has value `259` on all of my machines (see details above) and that's exactly what's causing my problem.

Comment: Have you tried calling gc(), R's garbage collection function, explicitly within the loop. In theory it should do GC automatically, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: That's why the Big Kids (TM) play with 64 bit operating systems and 8, 16, 32, 64, ... gb of ram.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: sure, and I do have a better box at work. But still, isn't it strange that removing objects does not seem to work? IMHO this should work regardless of the hardware you're running on...

Comment: @wkmor1: thanks, I forgot to add gc() in my example but added it just now. I did use it in the real use case though and still experienced the same memory increase.

Comment: On my Win64 XP, it works fine. The task manager shows a constant memory consumption that does not increase over time...

Comment: @Tommy: Thanks for taking the time! Hmm, that's strange. I've tried it with different configs (see update above) and also had my colleagues (both on Win XP 32) try it: same picture.

Comment: @Tommy: ha, seems that you're right! maybe it's the `gc()` I've forgot to add in the example in the first place that now takes care of everything. I'll double check. Still: I included `free()`, `rm()` and `gc()` calls in my real use case and memory went up.

Comment: Qs: Which version of R?  Which versions of necessary packages?  Did you look at `Rprofmem` & `Rprof`?  I'd also store the size of each file to be loaded.  FWIW, I don't think I've ever encountered this problem, and I definitely iterate through a lot of data and a lot of files.  I tend to do the heavier lifting in Linux, but I don't recall having this problem in Windows, either.  There are many possible causes, and it seems like others haven't yet reproduced this problem.

Comment: @Iterator: thanks, I answered some of your questions via an edit. The files are quite big, between 750 kB and 1.5 MB. I'll check `Rprofmem` and `Rprof` tomorrow. Seems like it's rather XML than Rdata that's causing the problem, but I'll have to double check

Comment: @Rappster - Well, to clarify, I only tried 'memory2.R'. And by now I've deleted the files...

Comment: @Tommy: right, "simple Rdata" scenarios seems to be no issue anymore after introducing `gc()` calls. If you find the time, could you try to reproduce my result of``~/memory.R` (see edit above)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A new version of the XML package fixed the bug. Thanks for your answers and comments!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `XML` package's webpage, it seems that the author, Duncan Temple Lang, has quite extensively described certain memory management issues.  See this page: ["Memory Management in the XML Package"](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/MemoryManagement.html).

Honestly, I'm not proficient in the details of what's going on here with your code and the package, but I think you'll either find the answer in that page, specifically in the section called ["Problems"](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/MemoryManagement.html#Problems), or in direct communication with Duncan Temple Lang.

---

Update 1.  An idea that *might* work is to use the `multicore` and `foreach` packages (i.e. `listResults = foreach(ix = 1:N) %dopar% {your processing;return(listElement)}`.  I think that for Windows you'll need `doSMP`, or maybe `doRedis`; under Linux, I use `doMC`.  In any case, by parallelizing the loading, you'll get faster throughput.  The reason I think you may get some benefit from memory usage is that it could be that forking R, could lead to different memory cleaning, as each spawned process gets killed when complete.  This isn't guaranteed to work, but it could address both memory and speed issues.

Note, though: `doSMP` has its own idiosyncracies (i.e. you may still have some memory issues with it).  There have been other Q&As on SO that mentioned some issues, but I'd still give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll have to turn to parallel/distributed programming anyway, so: why not give it a shot?! Also, I have Kubuntu living on my portable disc for quite a while now but never really made the transition to Linux yet. Maybe this is the last impulse that I needed ;-) At the risk of asking to much: would you mind sharing a short example of how you do your parallel computations on a linux box? Thanks a ton!

Comment: I just load up R, `library(foreach)`, same with `doMC` (and register the # of workers, often I set this to the # of cores), and then use `foreach` in most places where I'd use a `for` loop.  It's super easy.  The basic idea is that, after loading the packages, you "register" a backend and tell it how many cores to use.  After that, `foreach` and other frontends can send out the tasks to the cores, collect results, and output them.

Comment: So, as an example, I might have 10K files that I want to load in to a massive memory mapped (i.e. file-based) matrix, using the `bigmemory` (aka BM) package.  I do one pass to figure out the size of each matrix (even if they're of a constant size - just to be sure), then load each, select rows & cols to store, and bang those into the BM file.  Since the rows are disjoint, the processes can run independently, and this is a great use of `foreach`.  This particular workflow is ideal when the input HD is different from the output HD, or when one has an SSD available.

Comment: I used the Trojan horse approach with another packages that had memory leaks. I set up workers, did the work there, and closed the process. No more problems due to memory leaking.

Comment: A new version of the XML package fixed the bug. Thanks for your answers and comments!

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar issues with the XML package. The amount of memory being used by R was ballooning, to the point where my computer would crash. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849641/memory-leaks-parsing-xml-in-r) solved my problem, I just set `addFinalizer = F`.

Here's a minimum reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(XML)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
httr::GET(url) %>% base::saveRDS("html.rds")
```

**Memory usage before running anything else**:

[image]

---

**Memory usage after running the following**:

```
for(i in 1:10000){
    base::readRDS(file = "html.rds") %>% 
        XML::htmlParse(., asText=TRUE) %>% 
        XML::xpathSApply(., path = "//h1", xmlValue, addFinalizer = F)
}
```

[image]

---

**Memory usage after removing `addFinalizer = F` (the default)**:

```
for(i in 1:10000){
    base::readRDS(file = "html.rds") %>% 
        XML::htmlParse(., asText=TRUE) %>% 
        XML::xpathSApply(., path = "//h1", xmlValue)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

@Rappster My R doesn't crash when I first check and make sure the XML doc exists and then call the C function for realizing the memory.

```
 for (i in 1:1000) {

  pXML<-xmlParse(file)

if(exists("pXML")){
  .Call("RS_XML_forceFreeDoc", pXML)
                  }
}
```