# Memory leaks in R?

Tags: xml, r, memory-leaks, rcurl

I'm trying to parse some site using Rcurl and XML packages.
After ~1 houre of execution according task manager rsession process use 12G.
After calling

```
rm(list = ls())
gc()
```

all my memory is still used by rsession. What is the problem?
Here is the code:

```
  library(XML);
  library(RCurl);
  rm(list = ls())
  if (file.exists('cookies.txt')){
        file.remove('cookies.txt')
  }
  if (file.exists('words.txt')){
        file.remove('words.txt')
  }

  doGet <- function(url, encode = 'windows-1251') {
        html <- tryCatch(
              {
                    getURL(url, curl=curl, .encoding = encode)
              }, warning = function(w) {
                    print(paste('warning: ', url, w))
              }, error = function(e) {
                    print(paste('error: ', url, e))
              }, finally = {}
        )
        write(x = html, file = '~tmp.html', append = F)
        htmlTreeParse(file = '~tmp.html', useInternalNodes = T, encoding = encode)
  }

  makeURL <- function(url) {
        paste(url_base, url, sep = "")
  }

  parse.morph <- function(n){
        val <- xmlValue(n, encoding = 'UTF-8')
        res <- tolower(gsub(" |-", "", strsplit(val, ':')[[1]][[2]]))
        rm(val)
        res
  }

  morphToList <- function(morphs) {
        print(paste(morphs, collapse=''))
        res <- list()
        res$prefix = unlist(strsplit(morphs[1], split = ';'))
        res$base =   unlist(strsplit(morphs[2], split = ';'))
        res$suffix = unlist(strsplit(morphs[3], split = ';'))
        res$ending = unlist(strsplit(morphs[4], split = ';'))
        res
  }

  indexOf <- function(val, str) {
        grep(val, strsplit(str, "")[[1]])
  }

  parse.word <- function(page) {
        xpathSApply(page, "//div[@class='word-article']/ul/li", parse.morph) 
  }

  append <- function(df, m) {
        tmp <- data.frame(p1 =  m$prefix[3], p2 =  m$prefix[2], p3 =  m$prefix[1], 
                          b1 = m$base[1],   b2 = m$base[2],  
                          s1 = m$suffix[1], s2 = m$suffix[2], s3 = m$suffix[3], s4 = m$suffix[4], 
                          e1 = m$ending[1], e2 = m$ending[2], e3 = m$ending[3])
        rbind(df, tmp)
  }

  parsePage <- function(page) {
        words.url <- xpathSApply(page, "//tr[contains(@class, 'row')]/td/a", xmlGetAttr, 'href') 
        df <- data.frame(p1 = c(), p2 = c(), p3 = c(), b1 = c(), b2 = c(),  s1 = c(), s2 = c(), s3 = c(), s4 = c(), e1 = c(), e2 = c(), e3 = c())
        for(word.url in words.url) {
              page <- doGet(makeURL(word.url))
              word.morphs <- parse.word(page)
              df <- append(df, morphToList(word.morphs))
        }
        return(df)
  }

  saveWords <- function(df, fileName) {
        write.table(file = fileName, x = df, append = T, row.names = F, col.names = F, quote = T, sep = ',')
  }

  url_base <- 'http://slovonline.ru'
  url_addr <- makeURL('/slovar_sostav')
  agent<-"Mozilla/5.0"

  curl<-getCurlHandle()
  curlSetOpt(curl = curl, cookiejar='cookies.txt', useragent='Mozilla/5.0', followlocation=T)


  index <- doGet(url_addr)
  lrs.url <- xpathSApply(index, "//div[@class = 'nletters all']/a", xmlGetAttr, 'href') 

  for (letter in lrs.url[1:2]) {
        page <- doGet(makeURL(letter))
        table <- parsePage(page)
        pages.url <- c(letter, xpathSApply(page, "//div[@class = 'npages']/a", xmlGetAttr, 'href'))
        saveWords(df = table, fileName = 'words.csv')
        for (page.url in pages.url) {
              page <- doGet(makeURL(page.url))
              table <- parsePage(page)
              saveWords(df = table, fileName = 'words.csv')
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`XML`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) package is known to have memory management issues, as StackOverflow query reveals (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24497562/3552063), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20849641/3552063) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9220849/3552063)). Duncan Lang, author and maintainer of package, went as far as [writing paper about memory usage issues](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/MemoryManagement.html).

You might try Hadley Wickham's [`xml2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xml2/index.html) package, which promises better memory management than `XML`. Personally I have not verified this claim.

Last time when I had to scrape large amount of web data (about 20k pages), I have decided to rewrite entire thing in Python. There was no `xml2` back then.

Another approach I have tried was launching R script from shell loop. This way `rsession` process was stopped before it exhausted memory. It worked reasonably well, although was rather clumsy.

If you are interested, there is overview of algorithm:

- In shell:

  - check is file with `special-name` exists
  - if it does not exist, run [`r`](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) on R script file
  - repeat
- In R script

  - get sample of addresses from "yet-to-process" pool
  - if sample is empty ("yet-to-process" pool is exhausted) - create file with `special-name` (signal shell to stop execution) and finish
  - for each address: process it and remove it from "yet-to-process" pool